# How to use a for loop to create javascript object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I am trying to write a for loop to create a `columns` object like below:

```
columns: [
    {data: "productCode", title: "Product Code", width: "7%"},
    {data: "brand", title: "Brand", width: "10%"},
]
```

so far, I have tried:

Define each column attributes:

```
var ltColumns = {

    "col1": {data: "productCode", title: "Product Code", width: "7%" },

    "col2": {data: "brand", title: "Brand", width: "10%"}
};
```

Populate the column attributes with a `for` loop.

```
columns: [
        for (var key in ltColumns) {
            {
             data: ltColumns[key].data, 
             title: ltColumns[key].title, 
             width: ltColumns[key].width}
            }
         ];
```

However, I keep getting the error `Unexpected token for`. Can someone help me with the syntax?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the `for` loop outside of the array:

```
var columns = [];

for(var key in ltColumns) {
  columns.push({
    data: ltColumns[key].data, 
    title: ltColumns[key].title, 
    width: ltColumns[key].width
  });
}
```

I would suggest looking at [MDN's docs on `Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype).

The method I used above is `Array.prototype.push`, which pushes an item to the end of the array.

*Note: this is a common ES5 implementation.*

Comment: Unfiltered `for in` loops are dangerous I'd advise against them

Answer (score 3):

## ES7

That syntax, also known as *array comprehensions* are a very new feature in version of JavaScript called ES7. If you want to use this feature (currently only firefox supports this), you can do:

```
columns: [
    for (i of ltColumns)
    {
        data : i.data,
        title: i.title,
        width: i.width
    }
]
```

## ES6

A new version of JavaScript which is actually now very well supported in popular browsers called ES6 has features which can help when doing something like this:

```
columns: Object.keys(ltColumns).map(item => ltColumns[item])
```

## ES5

ES5 is the current version of JavaScript:

#### Method 1

You can do:

```
columns: Object.keys(ltColumns).map(function (item) { return
    ltColumns[item] })
```

#### Method 2

`for in` loops are also an option:

```
for (var i in ltColumns)
    columns[i] = ltColumns[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var columns = Object.keys(ltColumns).map(function (key) { return ltColumns[key]; });
```

Be careful, as it works slower than general solution with `for in`.

It always better to create helper function for common operations:

```
function values(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (e) { return obj[e]; });
}

someObject.columns = values(ltColumns);
```

But better to use fastest solution for helper functions.

```
function values(obj) {
    var result = [];

    for (var name in obj)
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name))
            result.push(obj[name]);

    return result;
}
```